# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST) localhost:5000/upload:1

Tags: javascript, html, flask, fetch

this is my html file

```
                // Send the data to the server
                fetch("http://localhost:5000/upload", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        // Data successfully sent to the server
                        console.log("File path sent to the server");
                    } else {
                        throw new Error("Error sending file path to the server");
                        console.log("ERROR")
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error:", error.message);
                });
            });
            fileInput.click();
        });
```

app.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS
# import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# logging.basicConfig(filename="server.log", level=logging.DEBUG)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("websitenew.html")


@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    # Process the request and generate a response
    data = {'message': 'Hello from Flask server!'}
    return jsonify(data)


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    # # Accessing all headers
    # logging.debug('Request Headers:')
    # for header, value in request.headers.items():
    #     logging.debug(f"{header}: {value}")

    # logging.debug('Request JSON Payload:')
    # logging.debug(request.get_json())

    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file found', 400
        
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    if uploaded_file.filename == '':
        return 'No file selected', 400

    file_path = f"./uploads/{uploaded_file.filename}"
    print(file_path)
    uploaded_file.save(file_path)  # Save the file to disk

    return jsonify({'file_path': file_path})


    # uploaded_file = request.files['data']
    # uploaded_file.save(uploaded_file.filename)  # Save the file to disk
    # # Process the uploaded file here
    # # Add your file processing logic

    # return 'Upload endpoint'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I tried to run app.py .I'm just a beginner in using js and flask when i run this code im getting an error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST) localhost:5000/upload:1
I think the link inside file have some problem.
anyone please help.im also new in using stack exchange.